# How can I set TouchScreenKeyboard active to false?

Tags: unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-gui

I have a game in unity where I instantiate a TouchScreenKeyboard:

```
keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open(
    "", //text
    TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default, //type
    false, //autocorrect
    true //multiline
);
```

Later, in `Update()`, I run the following:

```
keyboard.active = false;
Debug.Log("Turned off keyboard. Now: " + keyboard.active.ToString());
```

However, in my debugger (running on an iPhone through xcode), I only see:

> Turned off keyboard. Now: True

Where it gets really weird: the app does correctly start with the keyboard off on the screen, but if I log `keyboard.active` it says "True".

When I start the game, the keyboard pops up. However, it doesn't disappear after the game session (where I run `keyboard.active = false;` again).

If I unfocus the app at this time, however, the **keyboard disappears** and when I log the status as `Debug.Log(keyboard.active.ToString());` it shows false.

What gives? Is this a weird OS interaction? Should I just figure out a way to spoof unfocusing the app, or is there a trick I am missing to make this work? In the example code they use this exact line of code: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchScreenKeyboard-active.html

This is unity 2020.2.0f1